How to authenticate Node.js server to LDAP without LDAP.js
I have a project I'm working on that needs to authenticate it's users using an LDAP request. This project is a webapp with an Express and Node.js backend.
I'm new to LDAP but I recently found out one of the biggest packages, LDAP.js has been depricated for some time. For this project, I'm not allowed to use depricated packages, and actually I'm supposed to use as little packages as possible (contrary to the point of using Node, I know).
Because there is no LDAP package that meets my needs, I've decided to go ahead and try writing something from scratch that will handle authentication.
I tried using the HTTP and HTTPS packages to send a request but neither of those worked (for obvious reasons).
Does anyone have any ideas on what I could try to do?

LDAP is a binary protocol that is quite complex. It has nothing to do with HTTP, it uses ASN.1 BER encoding. Implementing even a simple bind is probably as large as your current project. The fastest way around this is to fork LDAP.js and call it your own (it won't be an external package anymore if it is in your tree). Better : avoid this nonsense and use OIDC login only. You will still be using a package, but it will not be deprecated.

@ixe013 what is OIDC? As I understand it, it would replace LDAP entirely? The project has to connect with a preexisting LDAP database. I like your forking idea though

OIDC is OpenID Connect. That's the "Login with Google" (or Microsoft and others) you see on web pages. Stackoverflow has it. You will get the users' email from the login. But that only solves your problem if you don't have existing users in your ldap server. If you do, you will still need an LDAP library to look them up (using the email and other attribuutes provided by OIDC).
